# Do you have to Save against Gaze attacks if you approach the target?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, saving-throw

The Universal Monster Rule [Gaze](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Gaze-Su-) indicates:

> Each opponent within range of a gaze attack must attempt a saving throw each round at the beginning of his or her turn in the initiative order.

If I approach such a creature, do I have to immediately roll a Save? Or does it only take affect when I *begin* my turn within its Gaze?

Comment: Just to be clear - are you asking about approaching the critter during combat? Or out of combat? Or both? Because I think the answer will vary.

Comment: I was specifically thinking in combat, but I'm not positive that matters since Gaze attacks are (generally) not something creatures have the option of not using. Many could close or cover their eyes in order to allow you closer to converse if they wanted, but then you wouldn't have to roll for it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, you don't.

To make the save, you have to begin your turn inside the area of the gaze attack, as [described by the ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Gaze-Su-). If you started your turn, then moved in, you will have to make the save on your **next turn**, or if the gaze is directed at you on the creature's turn.

> Thus, it is possible for an opponent to save against a creature’s gaze twice during the same round, once **before the opponent’s action** and once during the creature’s turn.

When the rules mention the *beginning of your turn*, that means you have to do it before you can act on your turn.

Comment: I can't be alone in thinking it's weird that this rule *encourages* folks to charge the medusa.

Comment: Iv seen what happens when folk charges the basilisks. They are still TPP (*team party petrified*).